# Can't find my disk after diskpart clean

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, ssd, diskpart

I have a PC with an SSD encrypted with BitLocker, I forgot the Admin password, and lost my BitLocker recovery key. I decided to reinstall Windows and wipe the SSD, but the Windows installer couldn’t find my disk on the list, so I used `diskpart`, following an article:

```
diskpart

  list disk
  select disk 0
  clean
```

- After `clean`, I didn’t execute the last command to create a new partition; when I closed Cmd and booted the installer, my disk does not appear during the wipe step or in `diskpart` [`list disk`]

It is an SSD drive, the PC is a Lenovo Ideapad 3. Unfortunately the PC does not detect it in Windows setup. I want to avoid removing the drive to plug it to a SSD rack and connect it to another PC.

Comment: But you're saying you weren't able to find the disk *before* diskpart clean as well, right?

Comment: Your question is very vague, the commands you entered in diskpart are all in one line, USB bootable couldn't boot is very non descriptive, these commands you didn't follow (what commands?). Please try make this clearer. Also tell what kind of hard drive you're using and if the PC itself (Setup) still detects it. As it is you run the risk of the question being closed due to lack of details etc..

Comment: @u1686_grawity coudn't find my disk with windows installer steps (wipe step) but I could reach it through Dispart commands

Comment: @JoepvanSteen I've edited my post, thank's for your comment
It is a SSD drive, the PC is Lenovo Ideapad 3, unfortunately the PC does not detect it in windows setup. I want to avoid removing the drive and plug it to a SSD rack and connect it to another PC

Comment: @Zikofs Is it the only disk in the machine? If so, it would be reasonable to try `select disk 0` and create a new partition.

Comment: @AndrewMorton yes it is the only one, can't do select disk 0 because list disk does not return any disk

Comment: @Zikofs Does the BIOS/UEFI see the drive? You could try resetting the BIOS to defaults.

Comment: There are only a few possible reasons an NVME won't be recognized by Windows Setup: hardware issue _(laptops usually have onboard hardware diagnostics accessible either via UEFI boot options page or from within the UEFI firmware - does Diagnostics and the UEFI firmware both detect the drive?)_; Incorrect UEFI settings for the drive _(possible enabling CSM [Legacy] Mode)_; UEFI firmware lacking the driver for NVME or the WinPE installer image used lacks it _(when and how was the installer USB created? Is the most recent UEFI firmware from Lenovo being used?)_ Is there more than one NVME slot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution, I did this in BIOS :

Disable Secure BOOT

Disable VMD controller (to show hidden SATA Controller mode)

Put SATA Controller mode on AHCI

And after I was able to install windows on my SSD

Thanks everyone